# How to disable 'save' option in Excel but 'save as'

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "You can't save this workbook!"
    Cancel = True    
End Sub
```

When we use this command to disable saving in Excel sheets that we have hidden, they are displayed from the user's view. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To disable Save, but allow SaveAs, try the following...

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If SaveUI = False Then
        MsgBox "You can't save this workbook!"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is not solved. When I enter this code, the sheets that were previously hidden are seen

Comment: Maybe you have some other code elsewhere that unhides those sheets?

Comment: No, I don't have another code to open the sheets
I disable tab sheets with this code:
     ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
But when I run the code to disable saving, the sheets tab is all visible

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce that behaviour.